# Perl XML::LibXML searching for attribute value and counting occurences

Tags: xml, perl, search, xml-libxml

So this code works to match attribute values from one source to another with exactly the same structure so I haven't shown the xml. I just figured with how flash XML::LibXML is, that there would be a much better way to do it

```
#get from one data source
for my $movie($review_details1->findnodes('/result_set/results/review')){
    my $id = $movie->findvalue('@movie_id');

    #check if it exists in the other data source
    for my $new_movie($review_details2->findnodes('result_set/results/review')){
        my $new_id = $new_movie->findvalue('@movie_id');
        if ($id eq $new_id){
        print "ID $id matches NEW ID $new_id\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: @Adam Taylor is right, here you iterate over review_details2 countless times, for each review_details1 again and again - that is quite a waste of cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my %ids1;
my %ids2;

# count all the IDs in Details1
$ids1{$_->value}++ foreach @{$review_details1->findnodes('book_reviewers/results/reviewer/@movie_id')};

# count all the IDs in Details2
$ids2{$_->value}++ foreach @{$review_details2->findnodes('book_reviewers/results/reviewer/@movie_id')};

# pass through all keys from IDs2 that also exist in IDs1
grep{exists $ids1{$_}} keys %ids2;
```

that grep statement will return the list of id's; for you to do with whatever you like, print it, assign it to an array - all yours.

Comment: However, I think there is a design-flaw in your XML-structure, where you put a movie_ID-attribute inside the <reviewer>-tag. ID's should be unique attribute values. Your movie_ID is just another data-entity, like <name> or <profession> and should have it's own <movie> element.
———
Since it is not, it will already have duplicate movie_ID's in either file, so the %ids counter will add up more and more, which makes this approach not a good solution.
———
Correct me if I am wrong, and thus the solution will work.

Comment: It now works with movie_id's that can occur — but should not — more than once in each file, it simply counts the ID's in each XML-Document and then checks if the keys of one hash-counter exists in the other.

Comment: I know what you mean VanHoesel, the movie id's should be unique, but in this case it is not. It is data that we have to use for an assignment but it is very flawed so I have been manipulating it, and learning at the same time (with a lot of thanks to your input). I have changed the data so that the same movie can have multiple reviewers. I am now thinking that I should add another attribute to the each review as a unique id. That is I was comparing id's  I had started a new data structure, and was going to check if a review  already existed in the new one, if not then add it

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off looping through each structure once instead of looping through the second XML each time, but, y'know, [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it). It probably doesn't matter if the XML files are small but if they were large it might be worth doing.

e.g.

```
my %movie_ids;
for my $movie($review_details1->findnodes('/result_set/results/review')){
    my $id = $movie->findvalue('@movie_id');
    $movie_ids{$id}++;

for my $new_movie($review_details2->findnodes('result_set/results/review')){
    my $new_id = $new_movie->findvalue('@movie_id');
    $movie_ids{$new_id}++;
```

Then you could look through `%movie_ids` and the value of each key would be either be 1 (no match) or > 1 (match).

You could combine both files first and then do something similar but only needing to look through one XML file.

Comment: Thanks - yep I knew it the code was bunky - it is great to see it in more than one way too, I am really learning a lot

Comment: Your attempt isn't wrong and it might not even matter that your looping through more times than you need, if the file is small. If you were dealing with larger files, then it's good to know other techniques. You learn this stuff as you go. Best of luck.